# Intersection of GridLines and line chart y-axis value

Tags: android, achartengine

I am able to display the AChartEngine's TimeChartView to user, but when the graph renders, the grid lines (vertical - set by showGridLines(true)) and the line drawn on graph to display corresponding y-axis value (time in secs) against the dates on x-axis don't intersect with each other.
The y-axis value pt shows up either before the x-axis value or after it, but not exactly on it.

Please suggest, if there's any achartengine property which needs to be set to get this done / any other thing that needs to be done for getting this done.

Thanks
Omkar Ghaisas

Sample Image --
[image: Sample Image showing Graph Misalignment wrt data points]

As can be seen, the points marked with ovals don't coincide with the vertical grid lines and with x axis values, but start before that. E.g the first y value for 7200 should start at vertical line of 02/03/2012, but instead starts before that. Similarly for all other data points.

Comment: Can you add a picture to show what you mean?

Comment: Edited the original question and added a image. Pls suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in the AChartEngine SVN.
Please see [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=205) for extra information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. I will get the latest code and use it as suggested.